# video_player crashes after working 15-20 times successfully

Tags: flutter, dart

we are using the video_player package. everything is updated to latest version.

```
flutter: 3.16.9
video_player: 2.8.2
```

our app is a watching app and we show mp4 videos to user. When user keeps watching for about 7 minutes (creating video player 15-20 times), the app throws an error.

not happening in debug mode, we found the  using sentry. I added the sentry log.

```
PlatformException
PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error m4.r: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.640015, -1, null, [270, 480, 23.99651], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES, null, null)
```

(i am sure that I dispose the controller every time.)